# Old records still showing on Sanity

Tags: gatsby, sanity

I have created a Sanity.io CMS, I have made some alterations to the schema after content had already been entered. The problem now is that the content is still saved somewhere inside the cms and I have no way to remove it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several ways of deleting documents which are no longer visible in the Studio:

- Make the Studio render the old documents, either by temporarily putting back the original schema, or defining a list using [Structure Builder](https://www.sanity.io/docs/how-it-works) which will render the old docs
- Write a script which queries for all documents by that type, and have the script delete them
- Use the Sanity CLI to query for and later delete the documents, e.g. `sanity documents query '*[_type == "unwantedType"]._id'` and then `sanity documents delete [list-of-unwanted-doc-ids]`

Comment: `sanity documents fetch` wasn't working for me; it looks like it has been renamed to `sanity documents query`.

Answer (score 0):

I re-imported the documents that I had changed/ removed back into the schema.js file and removed them via the studio. The other alternative, for now, is to use the API to delete the records.